# Spanish rental laws - scammed?

Tags: spain, rental, real-estate

We've rented an apartment in Catalonia and have now decided to move out after a gruesome four months. A lawyer has now told us that we need to pay upwards of €7000 to get out of the contract before it runs out.

Apparently, we unknowingly signed a five-year contract with a clause which mandates payment of one monthly rent per unfulfilled year. Whatever is still left in the current period of one year also has to be paid.

This is a huge bummer after already having to pay the fianza and I.T.P., especially because the real estate agent told us we would be able to terminate the contract after three months without additional costs. I feel lied to.

What can we do to avoid literally going bankrupt?

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but I have to ask how it is that you unknowingly signed up to this? Did you read the contract? Did you get anything in writing from the real estate agent about the 3 month no-penalty termination? Why have the 4 months you’ve spent there been ‘gruesome’ - anything in that contract which caused the gruesomeness that you could use to counter the claim for €7000?

Comment: I wonder if this isn't a question for the Law exchange site, though I'm unsure of the expertise there on internation stuff.

Comment: We had a talk with the landlord today and she does not seem to be aware of what the contract states in regards to termination. She simply told us to formally terminate the contract and she will even give us a month of rent off. No mention of any penalties. Most complaints are not enough to form a substantial counter claim, while they do add up. I was also unsure of whether to post on an international or law stack exchange.

Comment: @TemporaryName Given the previous advice you mention came from a lawyer, I’d ask your landlord to put her termination terms in writing